# Dynamic input for HTML shiny ui (index.html)

Tags: html, r, shiny

I would like to customize my shiny apps from scratch with html/css. Therefor I’m using index.html instead of ui.r and I encountered the following problem:

I’m using dynamic input in my ui.r, for example:

```
selectInput("var","Date",choices = format(Sys.time(),'%Y-%m-%d'))
```

which translates to:

```
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
  <label class="control-label" for="var">Date</label>
  <div>
    <select id="var"><option value="2015-08-10" selected>2015-08-10</option></select>
    <script type="application/json" data-for="var" data-nonempty="">{}</script>
  </div>
</div>
```

As i would have to use Sys.time() instead of the actual date in html code, I’m intrigued if it is even possible to call R/shiny while using only .html for the ui?

Comment: Instead of using `selectInput`, you can try having an `uiOutput` div in the html file, and adding the `selectInput` with `Sys.time()` from the `server.R` part of your app. See the Creating controls on the fly... part [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice NicE.

So I can create html output in server.r, for example:

  `output$date <- renderUI({ selectInput("var","Date",choices = format(Sys.time(),'%Y-%m-%d')) })`

And inclue it with pure html into index.html:

  `<pre id="date" class="shiny-html-output"></pre>`

Using selectInput this is totaly redundant but now I can create my own functions for the html parts.

Answer (score 0):

Shiny has a special function for this: `updateSelectInput`.

Leave `choices = NULL` or something like `choices = "Please Select Something."` in your ShinyUI (doesn't matter if generated through ui.R or index.html).

Then inside server.R, call `updateSelectInput` to change your `choices` attribute to whatever you want inside a reactive context.

Here some simple code example in a 1-file App:

```
app <- shinyApp(

  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    selectInput("inputID", label = "Reactive Select Input." , choices = "Please Select, Monsieur."), 
    actionButton("buttonID", label = "Refresh Select Options.")
  )),

  server = function(session, input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$buttonID, {
      updateSelectInput(session, "inputID", choices = as.character(Sys.time()))
    })

  }
)
```

Enjoy!